# Why does Javax' XPath evaluate() method not return elements with non-breaking space when the selector uses the text() node test

Tags: java, xpath, javax

I have the following Java code

```
    @Test
    public void notGettingNonBreakingSpace() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \n" +
            "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\n" +
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n" +
            "<body><table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></body>\n" +
            "</html>";

        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()));
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        int result = ((NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//tr/td/text()", document, XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength();
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }
```

The assertion fails, as `result` is `0`. If I take the HTML, however, save it as an `.htm` file, and open it in Chrome, `$x("//tr/td/text()")` in the Developer Tools Console returns as expected:

```
[text]
> 0: text
  length: 1
> __proto__: Array(0)
```

What do I need to do to get the same result in Java, i.e. a node list with one item?

Is there an "ignore whitespace" setting on the DocumentBuilder or the XPath object somewhere, or is the root cause that Java and Chrome's JS engine disagree how to handle that special whitespace character?

NB: Removing the `text()` (i.e. the text node selection) works; it then returns the right result. Replacing the non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) with actual text (e.g. `foo`) also works...

Comment: NB: We had an issue in the past where it tried to download the DTD, which we didn't want, hence the turning validation off...

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/scope.html). If you don't want to use external dtd, you should keep it disabled. But for Java xpath to work, include an entity for `nbsp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Java is not able to recognize `&nbsp;` when the dtd loading is disabled.

Your problem can be solved by writing an entity for `&nbsp;` in html like:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>`

The evaluate now gives one text node.

Comment: Does it not recognise the `nbsp` entity - or, presumably, any other entity - because loading external DTD is disabled? `setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);`

Comment: @Christian Right. Because you disabled the loading of external DTD it isn't recognized. I edited my answer. If you enable it, it can get the entity information of nbsp, not just nbsp any entity it can infer from the dtd.